# Only orange messages show up in the Android Logcat

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, logcat

I'm using PhoneGap to develop the android application with the help of Eclipse.

But since a long time ago, the logcat shows all kind of message(warning, error...) in orange color, and the information including PID/ Tag/ Time all disappear.

Here is the pic:
[image]

I tried to open another application and with different PhoneGap version but in vain.

Please help~

Comment: same thing happened to me .. it was fixed after updating sdk and adt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT is happenning when you are using an android device with latest api with an outdated sdk. For me I was using adt 16 and when I tried to run my app in jelly bean it appears. So I updated to latest sdk and this is solved.

To update the sdk in your eclipse Window > Android SDK Manager. From there you can install new packages.

To update adt download the latest ADT plugin from [here](http://tools.android.com/download). Then install it from Help > Install New Software then Local.

In my cases I had some problem for supportv4 library. I also updated it and reordered it to up. Else I dont think there is any other problem

Comment: How can I check my current API version? If I update my adt, will it cause the application not to run properly? What should I concern as I update my adt or API?

Comment: updating my answer wait a bit

Comment: Please wait. I will try it.

Comment: ok if there is any problem you face then tell me .. I am a recent victim :(

Comment: Do you mean if the API version on the android device is higher than  (or not match ) the one in Eclipse and the error will occur? I mean does that the API version on the device must `be the same` with the API version in the development environment?

Comment: no not same .. for example in my previous sdk there was no resource for api 16 in sdk .. so while I was running in 16 it was creating problem. .. but after updating the sdk manager The resources were there and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the filtered text **Error** from Textbox. This will filtered your logs with keyword. This Textbox was used for the search logcat which contains your input keyword

Comment: It's the same. Although I don't enter "Error", it remains.